# How to change inline css into internal css for table's rules attribution?

Tags: html, css

The table attribution rules=all can create lines without table's outermost  border.

```html
<table rules=all>
    <tr>
        <td>col1</td>
        <td>col2</td>
        <td>col3</td>
        <td>col4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>col1</td>
        <td>col2</td>
        <td>col3</td>
        <td>col4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>col1</td>
        <td>col2</td>
        <td>col3</td>
        <td>col4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

No outmost  border for the table created.
[image]

I am trying  to change the inline css into internal css with below styles.

```
<style type="text/css">
    table[rules="cols"]{
    }
</style>

<style type="text/css">
    table{
        rules:"cols";
    }
</style>
```

None of them take effect,how change inline css into internal css for table's rules attribution with same effect?

Comment: your shoud use css on table instead of these rules.

Comment: This is not inline-css. It is an attribute of the table-tag.

Comment: add frame="box" for outer border and these are attributes so no corresponding css for them is possible.

Comment: You must make use of `border` CSS property because `rules` is a HTML attribute and has no counterpart in CSS.

Comment: `table{
        rules:"cols";
    }` attributes can't be set with CSS

Comment: @Sahil Dhir: What did you think this question was for?

Comment: @BoltClock the OP wanted the css for those rules?

Comment: yes ,i want internal css to repalce inline css.

Comment: @Sahil Dhir: Yes. So why did you feel the need to point out that they should use CSS when *that's exactly what they're trying to do*?

Comment: @BoltClock : Apologize for that comment .I was confuse about the requirement earlier.

Comment: Some material say that internal css is more elegant than inline css.